# Why do paramagnetic materials require large fields to achieve magnetic saturation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm performing an experiment on a paramagnetic sample, and the field strengths we are applying range from -7T to 7T, which are impressively large field magnitudes.  However, we still are not observing total magnetic saturation.

My question is, why do we require fields strengths of increasing magnitude in order to achieve total magnetic saturation?  References for further clarification would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** For further clarification; my understanding (simply) is that magnetic dipoles will align with the applied magnetic field, and once all dipoles have aligned, magnetic saturation is achieved.  My question really pertains to as to why such a large field is required to achieve this.

Comment: Technically ideal paramagnets never sature. May you give more detail on the name the material and the values of the susceptibility involved?

Comment: The sample is dysprosium oxide (Dy2O3), with susceptibilities of 10^-4/10^-5 being observed (emu/Oe)

Comment: Paramagnet never sature experimentally. You would need fields of something like 100 T

Comment: Why don't they saturate though? What stops them from aligning perfectly with the applied field?